# Mysql Sentence take much time

Tags: mysql

I have 3 Tables: 
**News:** Id,title,date 
**Tags :** Id , name 
**News_Tag:** id_tag , id_news

And I have a search function with a mysql sentence like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    news.title,
    news.id,    
FROM
    news,
    tags,
    news_tag
WHERE
    news.date > now()
AND (
    news.title LIKE '%brasil%'
    OR (
        tags. NAME = 'brasil'
        AND news_tag.id_news = news.id
    )
)
```

Comment: You need to join the tables together in the `from` clause.  *Never* use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` syntax with an `on` clause.

Comment: I never used join syntax how would be with 3 tables?

Comment: The comma operator is the old school (and still valid) syntax for a JOIN operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you avoid using the old school comma operator syntax for join operations, and use the JOIN keyword instead.

```
SELECT DISTINCT news.title
     , news.id
  FROM news
  LEFT
  JOIN news_tag
    ON news_tag.id_news = news.id
  LEFT
  JOIN tags
    ON tags.id = news_tag.id_tag
 WHERE news.date > NOW()
   AND (news.title LIKE '%brasil%' OR tags.name = 'brasil')
```

Appropriate indexes will likely improve performance:

```
... ON tags (name, ...)
... ON news_tag (id_news, id_tag)
```

---

**NOTE:** This query, really a UNION set operation on two queries, will return an equivalent result:

```
SELECT news.title
     , news.id
  FROM news
 WHERE news.date > NOW()
   AND news.title LIKE '%brasil%'
 UNION
SELECT n.title
     , n.id
  FROM news n
  JOIN news_tag
    ON news_tag.id_news = n.id
  JOIN tags
    ON tags.id = news_tag.id_tag
   AND tags.name = 'brasil'
 WHERE n.date > NOW()
```

Comment: Don't forget an index on `news (date)`, and it seems unlikely that MySQL will use the index on `tags (name)`, probably `tags (id, name)` would be better.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: yes, definitely an index on `news` with a leading column of `date`. Even better, a covering index on `news (date,title,id)`. There's an equality predicate on `tags.name`, which makes the `name` column a good candidate for a leading column, to get a range scan operation to satisfy that predicate. It really depends on cardinality, distribution, number of rows, which plan is going to be optimum. It's queries with the "`OR`" (like this one) where the optimum plan is sometimes one different than I would expect.